# Extjs nested panel: scrollbar disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, nested, frontend

I'm working with extjs with two nested ext.panel.panel's.  The trouble is that when the text of the inner panel is enlarged, it outgrows the outer panel, hiding both important text and the right scrollbar.  Is there a way I could change things to make the inner panel always fit the outer panel?

The format is the following:

```
jController.centerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{    
  layout: 'border',    
  items: [{    
      region: 'center',    
      xtype: 'panel',    
      layout: 'fit',    
      items: [jController.queryResults]    
   }]    
}); 

jController.resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{    
  layout: 'border',    
  items: [{    
      region: 'center',    
      xtype: 'panel',    
      layout: 'fit',
      items: [jController.centerPanel]    
   }]    
});
```

Comment: Why so much nesting? Why border layouts?

Comment: Cause I'm reading someone else's code and am new to extjs.

Comment: Please put fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com) with error example!

Comment: Just remove the unnecessary border layout panels. The layout manager of extjs don't like this. Depending on your ExtJS Version see also the autoScroll Property: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-autoScroll